# How do I get Google to re-crawl my website and index only my new URLs?

Tags: seo, google

When I search my website on Google I get URLs like:
`http://example.com/article.php?movie=150`

And my new url is:
`http://example.com/online-stuff/150/title-of-article`

How do I get Google to re-crawl my website and index only my new URLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you properly 301 redirected all of your old urls to your new urls Google will eventually see this and update the urls in the search results.

If Google isn't crawling your site as much as you like, some simple rules to get it to crawl more frequently is to produce amazing content that it wants to send users to and to have a lot of links pointing to your domain.

The more relevant Google thinks your site is the more frequently it will crawl it. It uses all of the SEO on page and off page signals to determine this.

Sometimes, it just takes a little time.